# Angular - FormArray, how to reset a specific field of a formArray?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, formarray, formgroups

I can't figure out how to reset a single field of a FormArray, for example:

```
myForm = this.fb.group(
        {
            title: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
            date: ["", Validators.required],
            pairs: this.fb.array(
                this.fPairs.map(f =>
                    this.fb.group({
                        score: [],
                        value: [],
                        valueRel: []
                    })
                )
            )
        },
        {
            validator: minMaxValidator
        }
    );
```

so my FormArray is an Array of 4 Objects as it's mapped from:

```
fPairs: Array<fPairs> = [
        {score: 0, value: 0, valueRel: 0},
        {score: 0, value: 0, valueRel: 0},
        {score: 0, value: 0, valueRel: 0},
        {score: 0, value: 0, valueRel: 0}
    ];
```

what I achieved so far, to reset this part of my form, is:

```
pairsControl= this.myForm.controls["pairs"] as FormArray;
```

and then use:

this.pairsControl.reset();

but this resets EVERY field of the FormArray, and what I want instead, is being able to reset only a specific field,

for example the "`score"` field of all 4 objects, while leaving intact the value and the valueRel fields

I tried this:

```
this.fixedPointsControl.reset(["score"]);
```

but what it does, is reset everything like the previous expression, so nothing changes!

What s the correct way to reset a specific field of a formArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a `pairs` getter to get the `pairs` `FormArray`. Now in the `resetField` method set a parameter named `fieldName` that would expect the name of the filed on the `pairs` `FormArray` to `reset`

Something like this:

```
get pairs() {
  return (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('pairs'));
}

resetField(fieldName) {
  this.pairs.controls.forEach(group => group.get(fieldName).reset());
}
```

And then add these buttons to your template:

```
<button (click)="resetField('score')">Reset Score</button> | 
<button (click)="resetField('value')">Reset Value</button> | 
<button (click)="resetField('valueRel')">Reset Value Rel</button>
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reset-specific-controls-in-each-form-group-of-formarray?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: perfect, I ll be using this one instead of the one below, as it actually uses reset()! I have another question about this same formArray, posted yesterday, if you have any clue, still looking for help, it's about validators! Thank you anyway for the help

Comment: @AJ989, sure. Please share a link to that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53610059/angular-formarray-how-to-validate-different-fields-with-cross-validation

thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you have 4 fields inside your FormArray, you can reset it through its index since inside a FormArray is an Array of FormGroup so you can access it by its index.

> Had created a [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-form-array-reset-field) for your reference

```
const pairs = this.myForm.get['pairs'] as FormArray;   // Use 'get' instead of 'controls'

// Iterates the Pairs' FormArray controls and use patchValue if you want to reset or assign a new value to a particular property
pairs.controls.forEach(pair => pair.patchValue({ score: '' }));
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. Without 'controls' it won't work, I get: cannot read property 'reset' of undefined!

But if I keep 'controls' it would work!! But there is an issue, with your solution, it would reset the WHOLE 1st Formgroup! I don't want that, I want for example, to reset the property "score" for ALL 4 groups! but keep the other properties intact!

Comment: @AJ989 Had updated my answer and provided a Stackblitz demo link as well. Hope it helps :)

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! it works, but I'm going to use the other solution proposed above, as it actually resets the field instead of setting it to '', but really appreciete the help! if by any chance you are an expert on FormArray, yesterday I posted a question for a validator issue with this same formArray, if you know a solution, I would be happy to hear it! thank you